# Create-React-App displaying blank screen on IE11. ERRORS: SCRIPT5009: 'WebSocket' is undefined and SCRIPT5009: 'Promise' is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer, browser, error-handling

CRA works fine on every other browser but displaying blank screen on IE. I have tried installing react-app-polyfill 2.0 and 1.0.6, putting
import "react-app-polyfill/ie11"
import "react-app-polyfill/stable" at the top of src/index.js file. As well as putting "ie 11" in the browserList for dev and prod env. I also removed the .cache file in node_modules and still same error pops up. Here is my code:

[package.json file dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGtIA.jpg)

[paackage.json file browserList](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmI42.jpg)

[Polyfill imports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQsar.jpg)

Here are the error messages I am getting:

[Whole error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jclg5.jpg)

['WebSocket'is undefined points to this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6V8D.jpg)

['Promise' is undefined error points to this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAWLW.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

As we can see that you had already added the `react-app-polyfill` and added the `"ie 11"` in the browser list.

I suggest you keep those settings and refer to the steps below.

If this is a newly created app and not working with IE 11 then I suggest you install **core-JS** using the command `npm install core-js` and add `import 'core-js/stable'` on the first line in the `index.js` file.

The starting of the `index.js` file should look like below.

```
import 'core-js/stable';
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';
import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

After that delete the `.cache` folder under `node_modules` and again try to run the project. It may help you to run it in IE 11.

[image]

If your React app was working with IE 11 and you got this issue after adding some code then I suggest you try to provide detailed information about it. It can help us to understand the issue properly.

Thanks for your understanding.